# Laravel 4 error trying to create related items

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to create an application in PHP/Laravel 4, and having a problem.  I have a situation where I need to track multiple names for a given person, one of which is primary.  I have the tables defined as follows:

```
Schema::create('names', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('person');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});

Schema::create('people', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('primary_name');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

The idea is that a given person can have multiple names (as defined by the 'person' field on the names table), but only a single primary name (as defined by the 'primary_name' field on the people table.

Here are the models:

```
class Name extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required',
        //'person' => 'required'
    );

    public function personOwning()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Person','person');

    }

    public function primaryOf()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Person','primary_name');

    }


}
```

and

```
class Person extends Eloquent {
/*  protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array(
        //'primary_name' => 'required'
    );
*/
    public function primaryName()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Name','primary_name');
    }

    public function names()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Name','person');
    }

}
```

I am trying to simultaneously create a name and a person, and associate them.  The first part of the code is ($submitted is the name coming from an input form):

```
    $name = new Name;
    $name->name=$submitted;
    $name->save();

    $person=new Person;
    $person->primaryName()->associate($name);
    $person->save();
```

When I execute this, I get an error: "Undefined property: Person::$primary_name "
Note that I have not yet tried to create the second relationship.

This code looks right out of the examples in the Code Bright book, so I can't fathom what I'm doing wrong.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the name of the `primary_name` column to `primary_name_id` (which is good convention anyway), it should work. Laravel makes a lot of assumptions and converts a lot between snake-case and camel-case, so it  gets confused when you have an attribute (primary_name) and function (primaryName) that share the same name.

Comment: That worked, but the followup didn't.  I've made the change you suggested, and on the names table I changed `person` to `person_id`.  But placing this as the next line: `$name->personOwning()->save($person);` results in "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()".  If I change `associate` instead of `save` I get no error, but it doesn't make the connection, either.

Comment: What type of relationship is `$name->personOwning`? HasOne?

Comment: belongsTo, it's in the Name model, above.

Comment: In this context, you have to use associate. The logic here is that $person needs to be explicitly saved before you can attach a BelongsTo item to it. Otherwise, Laravel won't know which id to put in the person_id field.

Comment: Thank you, problem resolved.  I was just being an idiot - failed to `save()` after using `associate()`. Thanks for your help.